# NetSuite Script to Block the order if payment is rejected

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I using Web Services to integrate to NetSuite and passing the internal ID of the credit card on file for the customer with my sales order transaction header.

I would like NetSuite to fail to create the order completely if the card that I am passing cannot be authorized (for example if it's expired). Is this possible using a script in the custom form?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a pre-auth in NetSuite. You would need to make a call to AuthNet or something first. Or you can close/reject the order if the CC fails after saved.